# jQuery Datatables - Show Last Page First

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery DataTables plugin (https://datatables.net/). I am trying to get the last page to be the first page. I am sorting by date and would like the latest entries to be at the bottom of the visible area.

So if the "Records per page:" is 10, then the latest date should be at the bottom. I am using the plugin to create a "logbook" so the latest entries should always be at the bottom. I have tried the following but I can't get it to work:

**jQuery**

```
// On page load: datatable
var table_companies = $('#table_companies').dataTable({

    "ajax": "data.php?job=get_companies",
    "sDom": '<"top"lB><"clear">rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
    "language": {
     "paginate": {
      "previous": "Older Entries"
      }
     },

    "autoWidth": false,
    "searching": true,
    "columns": [
      { "data": "date" },
      { "data": "type",   "sClass": "company_name" },
      { "data": "registration" }

      ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }
    ],
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100]],   
    "pagingType": "simple",
    "oLanguage": {

      "sLengthMenu":    "Records per page: _MENU_",
      "sInfo":          "Total of _TOTAL_ records (showing _START_ to _END_)",

      "sInfoFiltered":  "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
  }
});
  table_companies.fnPageChange( 'last' );
```

I am using this link to load my plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/dt-1.10.11,b-1.1.2,b-colvis-1.1.2,b-print-1.1.2,cr-1.3.1,r-2.0.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code:

`$('#datatable').DataTable().page('last').draw('page');`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was as simple as capitalizing the "D" in dataTables.

Changed:

```
var table_companies = $('#table_companies').dataTable({
```

to:

```
var table_companies = $('#table_companies').DataTable({
```